# Downgrading tshark to 1.*

Tags: wireshark, tshark, downgrade

For my current tool i need to use the -T ek option of tshark. As in tshark 2 -T ek option is not there, i have to degrade the tshark version. Can anyone help me with downgrading tshark or installing tshark 1.* in ubuntu

Comment: Can you clarify?  Both 1.* and 2.* support the -T and -e options; neither support a -k option.  I'm sure you mean something else, but I don't know what.

Comment: -e option is to specify the individual fields. I am asking about ek option which is similar to text, pdml or pxml in tshark 2